# Changes in code are not reflected until I execute it twice in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, execute

Today I am writing my java code and getting some strange problems in Eclipse.
I have to execute code twice before I can see the changes take effect in the runtime. I tried to start eclipse with -clean option, I also tried to clean my project, but problem still exits.

My code does not depend on external libraries and changes are trivial as I am just trying to solve problems in LeetCode.

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: are you running your programs in console mode?
you could not terminate older consoles (running another console java program causes another console to run and it just might get above the last build in eclipse consoles container)

Answer (score 0):

If you had executed your program before and it finished, it didn't dissapear at all. You will have it in a secondary level and you have to terminate it.

So, to solve this problem, in Eclipse you will have to go to the console:

1. If your program had been executed, in the right corner of the console you will see 2 grey cross that are overlap one behind other.
2. If your program was blocked (maybe by an infitive loop or something like that) you will be able to stop the execution of the current program (you have to press red square that it's position in the right corner of the console). If you see the grey cross that we said in the another step then press them to terminate and clear your

Let me know if it works for you, please.

Comment: grey cross button does help me get the correct result in one execution, but does it mean I need to use it every time I execute the program?

Comment: Yes, it is. You have to press grey cross each time you are going to execute a program and you had executed another one before. It is because, if you don't do that, it could be errors of the first one execution or maybe if you execute it, and it works, maybe it will catch the features of the first one execution and not the changes that you make after that.